# Can you add the date value of when you ran the query into the results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query that I'm trying to write, and anytime it's ran, I'd like to see the date value of when it was ran. Preferably I'd like the date shown in one column and one row. Is this possible? Thank you!

My current code is,

```
SELECT 
     comp_code,
     a.cust_code, 
     a.item,
     NVL(b.item_des1, 'TOTAL PALLETS') as description,
     COUNT(a.chep) as CHEP, 
     COUNT(a.stdp) as STDP
FROM t1 a
LEFT JOIN m_item_h b
ON a.comp_code=b.comp_code AND a.cust_code=b.cust_code AND a.item=b.item_code
GROUP BY
GROUPING SETS ((a.comp_code),(a.comp_code, a.cust_code, a.item, b.item_des1))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just select the date:

```
select sysdate, . . .
```

If you want only the date and no time component:

select trunc(sysdate) as today, . . .

I'm not sure what you mean by in only one row.  All rows have the same column, so you might as well include the date in all of them.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Yes this worked when I tried it previously. Customer was picky and asked if the report could be cleaned up so the date wasn't showing in all 100 rows. I guess he'll have to live with the results :) Much appreciated.

Comment: @mrdiu . . . It is a little tricky because of `grouping sets`.  This might work:  (case when rownum = 1 then sysdate end)`.

Comment: I tried it out, it didn't work. Not a group by expression. I appreciate the efforts!